# Intellij idea и java 7

Tags: ide, java, intellij-idea

Злравствуйте. Вознкла проблема, установил java 7, но никак не могу настроить idea под новую версию. Например, если использовать String в switch, то выдает ошибку при компиляции, хотя не должен этого делать, выдает вот [такую](http://gyazo.com/ab0ea4bd4f7c1791fcd442425db128e9) ошибку при компиляции такого кода:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.nextLine();
    switch (s) {
        case "qq":
            System.out.println(1);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Меню File -> Project Structure

Убедитесь что поле Project SDK указывает на правильую SDK. В поле Project language level выберите "7.0 - Diamonds, ARM, multi-catch etc."

Answer (score 1):

https://risik.info/?p=444

Почти в самом конце.

Да и в ошибке явно написано, что нужно использовать параметр "-source 7" в параметрах jvm.